# Can a verb then preposition then noun make an independent clause?

Tags: verbs, nouns, prepositions, independent-clauses

Can a verb then preposition then noun make an independent clause?

e.g.

> he ignored how much it hurt, and the **fear of death**.

or

> he prayed for miracles, and the **love of god**.

I've tried to make it these independent clauses by using them after an independent clause, comma and conjunction. So, I hope to show that they are independent clauses. Apologies if that's made the question worse.

Both seem to contain a noun (death / god) and verb (love / fear), but it's not clear that they make sense on their own, so that the noun is predicated something. Unlike, I suppose

> God loves.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Verb - preposition - noun* works, e.g.

> Go for coffee.

*Noun - preposition - noun* doesn't work as a stand-alone clause because it has no verb.

Comment: let's go for coffee! ha ;)

Comment: further comment / voting on this exciting answer would be much appreciated :) !

Answer (score 4):

In your examples, *fear* and *love* are most likely nouns, not verbs. Hence they cannot stand alone as sentences; they're just phrases. In English, words sometimes do not change form when they change from one part of speech into another, such as from verb to noun.

Comment: well you may well be right. but what about the question title?

Comment: is there any way i can convince you that they are verbs, or construct a sentence which is unambiguously verb / of / noun?

Comment: @user3293056 "fear" and "love" in your examples are definitely nouns; you can't put an article before a verb.